# Why does hex value is returned as a number in javascript

Tags: javascript, hex

I tried the following code in a browser console.

```
var testingVar = 0xffff00;
```

When I access the variable it returned me the value `16776960` instead of the hexa value. Why does this happen? can't we store hexa value in the variable.

Comment: data != representation.

Comment: They are the same. Hex is not a "value" but a representation of a value. The value is of type number.

Comment: You can store hex values in strings. Use `parseInt(str, base)` to convert an octal or hexadecimal string to a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "hex value" in Javascript. There are strings and numbers.

`0xffff00` is just an alternate syntax for specifying a number. By default the console will print numbers in decimal (base 10), which is why you see `16776960`.

You can see a string representation of the number, using a different base with the [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method.

```
// hex
(0xffff00).toString(16) // "0xffff00"
// decimal
(0xffff00).toString(10) // "16776960"
// octal (for good measure)
(0xffff00).toString(10) // "77777400"
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "hex value" in ***programming languages***

Comment: @slebetman in general your statement cannot be true for every case. It is fine for a programming language to have a dedicated type that represents hex values specifically.

Comment: This issue occurred to me when I was using grunt web font and it has asked me to pass a `0xE001` but in javascript I cannot pass that.

Comment: @zerkms: Yes, but it is true for all existing cases as of November 2015. In the future someone may decide to do it but not yet to the best of my knowledge (and I've looked at a lot of languages in my 15 years of programming)

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri: It may want that value as a string, not a number. In which case it's not a hex value, it's a string zero, ex, ee, zero, zero, one

Comment: It's actually a misleading documentation example. It actually accepts converted integer values but in the doc it says it accepts `0xffff00`. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hexadecimals in Javascript.

When you need to convert an octal or hexadecimal string to a number, use the function `parseInt(str,base)`. Consider these examples, first you should define like below

```
var testingVar = '0xffff00';
```

And when you need you can call like below:

```
num = parseInt(testingVar, 16);
```